# Instruction FYL2XP1

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, instructions, x87

I'm wondering why the instruction `FYL2XP1` on x86-architecture computes exactly the mathematical formula  *y* · log<sub>2</sub>(*x* + 1).

What's special with this formula?

Comment: Why would you untag x87 on a question about an x87 FPU instruction?  That's the most specific and relevant tag here.

Comment: this is useful so the C++ standard library also includes it: [std::log1p](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) and [std::expm1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/expm1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `y` operand is usually a compile time constant, for the moment forget about the `x + 1`.

Since `log_b(x) = log_b(2) * log_2(x)` the instruction allows to compute the logarithm in any base of `x + 1`.
Note that `log_b(2)` is a constant since it is seldom necessary to compute the logarithm with a degree of freedom in the base.

`FYL2XP1` and `FYL2X` are the only two x87 instructions that compute the logarithm.
If the logarithm was an algebraic function a single instruction would suffice, but since it is transcendental, Intel provided two versions.

`FYL2X` works on the full domain of the logarithm but it is not perfectly accurate over this full range, particularly for very small values of `x` (and probably slower, I believe it has to do a range reduction, use a truncated Taylor expansion or a Padé approximation and then improve the accuracy with a table lookup).

`FYL2XP1` instead works only for input in the small range ±( 1 – sqrt(2) ⁄ 2 ).
This should be faster (because of no range reduction) and more importantly, for the given input range, the approximation method used should have a precision equal or greater than the x87 80-bit floating point precision.

> This instruction provides optimal accuracy for values of epsilon [the value in register ST(0)] that are close to 0. For
> small epsilon (ε) values, more significant digits can be retained by using the `FYL2XP1` instruction than by using
> (ε+1) as an argument to the `FYL2X` instruction.

[@Mysticial's comment is a spot on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736011/instruction-fyl2xp1/52740887?noredirect=1#comment92418458_52740887):
The algorithm used by `FYL2X` is probably using, after all the other necessary steps, an approximation formula for `log(x + 1)`.
To transform this into a formula for `log(x)` the input must be subtracted by one. An `x - 1` operation will lose precision if `x` is very small (because the big difference in the exponents of the two numbers will shift most of `x`'s digits off to the right).
`FYL2XP1` doesn't do `x - 1` and hence won't lose precision.

Comment: The Taylor series for `log(x)` is usually done about `x = 1`. So every term will have `x - 1`. If you're trying to compute `log(x + 1)` for a very small `x`, a direct call as `log(x + 1)` will result in `x + 1 - 1` which will drop all the low-order bits of `x` - thereby losing precision if `x` is really small. A built-in `log(x+1)` can then elide this `x + 1 - 1` step and preserve the full precision.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, good point! There are quite a few hints in the manuals to believe the instructions are using an approximation around x=1, even though the actual algorithm is not revealed. But your phrasing is excellent because it focuses on the real problem here: approximations done about x=1 will  have a x-1 term and 1 >> x means a loss in precision. Thank you very much! P.S. Do you happen to know why Intel chose that specific input range for `FYL2XP1`?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but sqrt(2)/2 is 1/sqrt(2) which ensures a converge rate of 0.5 bits/term or better for the series. Maybe the tables are only hard-coded to 106 or 128 terms? The problem is that if the instruction is supposed to give a full 64-bits of precision for 80-bit FP, it's going to have multiple ulps of error unless it works with an even higher internal precision - regardless of the convergence rate.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks but I'm afraid I don't follow you. AFAIK the convergence rate is a property of the series not of the input domain. Where does the 0.5 bits/term figure come from?

Comment: @Mysticial IIRC, the original 8087 carried an additional three bits for internal computations, i.e. 67 mantissa bits in all. Check John F. Palmer, Stephen P. Morse, "The 8087 Primer", Wiley 1984 if you need to know for sure. Error in FYL2XP1 < 1 ulp if y=1, I think. For the x87 FPU inside the AMD Athlon Processor, we used 68-bit internal precision. See: Stuart F. Oberman, "Floating Point Division and Square Root Algorithms and Implementation in the AMD-K7™ Microprocessor", In *Proceedings 14th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic*, pp. 106-115. IEEE 1999. Error in FYL2XP1 < 1 ulp for any x, y

Comment: @MargaretBloom I was assuming the standard Taylor Series for log(x - 1). That one will converge at 0.5 bits/term with the `1 +/- 1/sqrt(2)` boundaries. Of course we don't know for sure.

Comment: @njuffa Woah. That's good to know. Didn't realize it! Thanks.

Comment: @Mysticial Eh, that's what I don't follow: how from the Taylor series for log(x + 1) within that range one arrives at 0.5 bits/term. The term i-th approximately corrects the series by 2^-(i+1). If, when you have time, you could explain it I'd be grateful :) It's just curiosity

Comment: The series is `log(x+1) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4...` The denominator is linear so it's negligible. The `x = 1/sqrt(2)` will drop by a factor of 2 every two terms. (since `x^2 = 1/2`) Thus 0.5 bits/term. Likewise for a given `x`, the convergence rate is `-log(|x|)/log(2)` bits/term where `|x| < 1` over the complex plane. Outside those bounds it diverges.

Comment: @Mysticial Taylor expansions are rarely used to compute transcendentals in fixed-sized FP arithmetic. Rafi Nave, "Implementation of Transcendental Functions on a Numerics Processor", *Microprocessing and Microprogramming* 11 (1983) 221-225 states that the 8087 used a combination of CORDIC and rational approximations (presumably of the minimax kind) to compute transcendental functions. For the Athlon, for log2(1+x) on the primary approximation interval I made use of the identity log(1+x) = 2*atanh(x/(x+2)), and used a rational minimax approximation to compute atanh(). Very few terms are needed.

Comment: @njuffa Good to know. I figured CORDIC would come into play at some point. Admittedly, most of my experience is on the arbitrary precision side.

Comment: @Mysticial Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense :) I figured you meant how fast the error was halving (the convergence rate is how fast the error goes to zero) due to the use of the bits/term unit but I kept the denominator and got tricked by it since it makes the series half at about 1 bit/term for the first 10 terms.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the common description of this instruction contains an inaccuracy. Historically, this instruction did *not* work in the range ±(1 – sqrt(2) ⁄ 2), but rather in the range sqrt(2) ⁄ 2 – 1 <= x <= sqrt(2) – 1. This is a convenient range of approximation of this function using a series expansion (e.g. by Chebyshev method). This seems to be true because then the left and right boundaries of the range for the argument of the logarithm (x + 1) differ by a factor of 2, which makes it relatively easy to extend the result of this function to any x > -1.
It is important to note that in all modern processors, the `fyl2xp1` instruction supports any x > -1, and this feature can be safely used. But you need to remember that this instruction does not throw an exception in case of an erroneous argument.

Comment: While plausible, in Intel's processor documentation for the 8087 / 80287 the argument restrictions on `FYL2XP1` are clearly stated as 0 ≤ |ST(0)| < (1 - (√ 2 /2)). Consistent with this, the publication by the lead engineer: R. Nave, "Implementation of Transcendental Functions on a Numerics Processor", *Microprocessing and Microprogramming*, Vol. 11, No. 3-4, March-April 1983, pp. 221-225, states the restriction as (√ 2 /2)-1 < X < (1 - (√ 2 /2)). I can confirm from personal implementation experience that the permissible range for X was extended to all X > -1 in later x87 implementations.

Comment: J.F. Palmer and S.P. Morse, "The 8087 Primer", Wiley 1984, likewise states the argument restriction on `FYL2XP1` as |x| < 1- √ (1/2).

Comment: Unfortunately, the correctness of the range given in these sources is almost impossible to verify - a working system with an 8087 coprocessor is needed.